# Why should I use Java EE server libs instead of app libs?

Tags: java, performance, tomcat, weblogic12c

We have an application which includes all libs (jsf,javassit,slf4f vs ... ) in it. Because we developed it on tomcat and tomcat does not provide any additional library. We are trying to move it on Java EE servers like Weblogic,Jboss, Websphere vs ...

My question is why should I prefer server libs instead of my application libs? Do server libs provide better performance? 
I can change class load order and I can use those servers just a servlet container.

Comment: Do the server libs work for you? If yes, then you can use server libs instead of packaging extra libraries. You may want to think about whether all the jars that your application needs are compatible with each other. Not aware of any particular performance gains.

Answer (score 2):

IMO the memory savings do not apply. In the past, people used multiple applications on one application server (AS). If they all referenced the same library, you save memory.

But that's insane nowadays. Each application should have it's own AS anyway for security reasons alone (and preferably in it's own Docker instance).

I would advise against using the AS's libraries: their upgrade path does not always align with yours (as a developer). This could bring you (dev) in trouble. But from the ops side it's nice for them because of the 'stability' of it all.

My recommendation: disable the AS libraries and include your own. With JBoss it's as simple as this for example:

In WEB-INF folder file jboss-deployment-structure.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.0">
  <deployment>
    <exclusions>
       <module name="org.hibernate"/>
          <module name="org.jboss.logmanager.log4j" />
          <module name="org.slf4j" />
          <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
    </exclusions>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

My own hibernate & logging. Things are once again as they should be.

AS manufactures want you to implement their libraries and code against their implementation, and before you know it you're married to that specific AS. Don't be fooled.

Only one advantage stays when using the full AS route: decreased war size. You can save up to 30Mb. I guess this was an advantage back in 1999..

Comment: well said. Many are abandoning app servers because many of the premises and principles they are built on are not applicable or outweighed by other concerns. The largest design flaw being, updating your application server should not break your application. When you are using the AS libraries an upgrade will inevitably break your app. I can't tell you how many times I have had to make application changes and special builds to accommodate this AS vs that AS (even minor versions). Javaasist and logger conflict's, JSF/Hibernate library bugs, etc. Avoid using AS libraries as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Server libraries have following advantage:

- Most important: no version conflicts between app server core and your code. Java EE server have to provide some API classes to your application by specification. It is important have no duplicate of these classes inside war/ear
- Decrease size of war/ear
- Decrease memory consumption by server

Also it makes life easer, when you switch to new version of application server. E.g. if you use maven and wildfly then [Wildfly BOM](https://github.com/wildfly/boms) provides centralization place for information about libraries. You can edit one line in maven pom when switching to new version of wildfly.

Answer (score 0):

Using Server Libraries need not necessarily provide any performance benefits, however, you must understand the reason why they are preferred over application libraries.

Libs/JAR files can be implicitly referenced.

If you have several different applications that make use of, say, the Spring framework, it might be easier to put the Spring JAR files into a common location that all of the utilities can reference. Doing so avoids having multiple copies of JARs popping up all over the filesystem.

The Java runtime's common location for JARs, known as the "extension directory," is by default located in the lib/ext subdirectory, underneath the installed JRE location.

The JRE is a customizable location, but it is so rarely customized within a given Java environment that it's entirely safe to assume that lib/ext is a safe place to store JARs, and that they will be implicitly available on the Java environment's CLASSPATH.

This will eventually make deployment a lot simpler!

Answer (score 0):

Many of the common application configuration aspects now days are driven by Java EE app servers like maintaining a **datasources ( db connections ) , JMS and EJB** settings. Java EE server then provides lookup mechanism such as **JNDI** etc.. to access these functions. So all the relevant jars should be part of Java EE servers lib folder.

Now all common jars pertaining to many applications can be maintained in j2ee server lib but nowdays maintaining it in central repository like **nexus / maven** is more suitable option

Comment: Your own libs should also be able to acces the datasource, JMS & EJB settings, no?

Comment: No need once you setup lookups i.e. JNDI etc

Answer (score 0):

Using the libraries loaded by the server saves you lots of *memory*, if there are other webapps that use the same libraries. They only have to be loaded once. If there aren't other such webapps there is no difference.

Comment: Other webapps on the same server?.. Not that secure eh?

Answer (score 0):

For a Java EE server there's really only one reason:

**Because Java EE is designed to have this functionality at the server**

You can compare this with the JDK, where something like `java.util.HashMap` is intended to be part of the installed JDK. You are not supposed to include this with your application.

You can also compare this with Tomcat when it comes to the Servlet, JSP, EL or WebSocket classes (which ultimately exist as jars too in Tomcat). You don't include those in your war either, since they are part of Tomcat, not of your application.

In Java EE many of its constituent parts (like JSF, JPA, CDI, etc) have parts that are largely independent of other implementations, but also parts that are application server specific. This is called the SPI code, or the integration code. This makes it possible that CDI beans can be injected in Servlets, CDI can add a scope to a stateful session bean (and subsequently destroy the bean when the scope ends) and much more.

Because of this integration aspect, it's generally not possible to update implementation jars (e.g. JSF) from within the war, let alone swap out implementation jars with a different implementation (e.g. Mojarra for MyFaces).

Now some servers have limited support for specific implementations. E.g. since there are only two JSF implementations, a vendor could support them both and allow you to swap them. Unfortunately, it's a miss and hit whether this works and by far not all functionality of Java EE is supported this way, if it's supported at all. E.g. Servlet, JSP and EJB are notoriously difficult to swap, despite several early efforts here.

In general the advantages of having these implementation jars at the server level separate from the application archive is startup and redeploy time, and a clear separation between application and framework code. Specifically, Java EE implementation jars like JSF do not have to be scanned for annotations each time you restart/redeploy your application.

At any length, Tomcat is a kind of intermediate solution. You'll have some classes/jars at the server level (Servlet, JSP, EL, WebSockets as mentioned) and some in your war (JSF, JPA, etc). This is IMHO not entirely optimal either.

Another option that has come into fashion lately is to deploy the entire application server + application as a single runnable jar ("fat jars"). It's beyond the scope of this answer to go into much detail here, but lookup e.g. [WildFly Swarm](http://blog.arungupta.me/wildfly-swarm-microservices-javaee) or [Payara embedded/micro](http://www.payara.co.uk/using_payara_embedded_and_payara_micro_with_mav).

*p.s. it has already been mentioned a couple of times in other answers, but I like to stress too that deploying several unrelated applications to a single application server and then expect to get memory benefits is generally not such a good idea. The problems with security and resource utilization, as well as with upgrading IMHO far, far outweigh any potential memory savings.*

Answer (score 0):

The biggest reason I use for Application Server libraries is enterprise consistency.

In a company you have multiple teams all building applications, if all teams just cobble together jar files into their war file, then they are effectively rolling their own application server. This burns a lot of developer resources as they try to figure out the exact versions of different jars that work okay together. It also means that I would then have DevOps supporting a bunch of different versions of JPA, JMS Queue, Clustering, Caching, etc...

If I have my teams standardize on an app server I know there will be less surprises in production. I can purchase support from the app server vendor and know that when the cache isn't working there is one clear way to get it fixed.